# Stepper motor dimensions reading

Tags: stepper-motor

how to read the dimensions phi A,D,E at the pins 1+ / 1- /2+/ 2-

[image: stepper motor]

Comment: what is the dimension of the pins 1+ / 1- /2+/ 2-. how to read them

Comment: It's not "Phi A,D,E." It is "Center, 1mm diameter, referencing marks A, D, and E." This is all rather confusing. I'd suggest you just ignore these, as they add nothing useful except the diameter.

Comment: the pins are squared shape. how can they give  dia for square shape pins?